# Drawing ALB RequestPerCountPerTarget accurately on AWS Cloudwatch Dashboard

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatch-metrics

The AWS ALB Target Groups have a metric "RequestCountPerTarget" that seems at first sight very interesting. However, this metric only seems to be displayed accurately on the full detailed view of the metric, and it is completely screwed over when it appears along with other metrics on the CloudWatch dashboard.

When I configure the metric I have this, which is the correct that is the most useful for me, ie. the number of requests per minute received by a single server

[image]

Using this graph, I can quickly determine if my application is overloaded or not : from the average response rate of my servers, I can deduce a max RPM (Requests per Minute) a single server can tank (which happens to be around 200 RPM/server in my case)

However, on the CloudWatch Dashboard, this metrics appears like this

[image]

If my understanding is correct, The AWS CloudWatch dashboard uses interpolation in order to avoid requesting to many datapoints, but in this case, what the interpolation seems to be doing, isn't to make an **average** of "RequestCountPerTarget during 1min" over the dashboard period (1 week in the screenshots), but a **sum** of "RequestCountPerTarget during 1min" over the dashboard period, which completely destroys the purpose of the metric : I don't care about the total number of requests received over 1 week (since if those requests are distributed evenly during the time frame, this basically means nothing to my servers), but I do care about the average maximum number of requests received in 1 minute over 1 week (since this will reflect the actual request spikes).

Is there a way around this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your first graph, you have the period set to 1 minute, and CloudWatch respects that.

When you put that graph on the dashboard and change the time range of the dashboard, CloudWatch will adjust the period to have the dashboard load faster.

You can change that behaviour by going to the `Actions -> Period` on the top of the dashboard when you have it opened and change the value from `Auto` to `Do not override`. This will make the dashboard respect the period you have set on the graph.

To make the change permanent, go to `Actions -> View/edit source` and put `"periodOverride": "inherit"` above the widgets list (make sure to save the dashboard, doesn't save automatically ...).

```
{
    "periodOverride": "inherit",
    "widgets": ...
}
```

For more info:

- CloudWatch Dashboards body structure: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/APIReference/CloudWatch-Dashboard-Body-Structure.html
- CloudWatch concepts (period): https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/cloudwatch_concepts.html#CloudWatchPeriods

Comment: Thanks ! this makes it much easier to spot anomalies with this inherit mode. Do you know if this is possible to specify this `periodOverride` on a per metric basis ? There are some graphs where it would make sense to adapt the period based on the cloudwatch dashboard, others no.
Also, do you know if this has a strong impact on thr pricing ? For example, since I force the period to be much lower (requests per minute), will the become billed exponentially more expensive if I look at data of the past 3 months with minute resolution?

Comment: I don't think this can be applied per metric. You are not billed for metric data requested through the dashboard, just over APIs. Even there, you would be billed per metric requested and per requests made, not per datapoints requested.